# How to count the maximum number of consecutive values in SAS

Tags: arrays, count, sas

I have a dataset that has one row per patient, and it contains information on what date (formatted as a SAS date) a patient took 11 doses of medication.  In the dataset, there is at most one dose of medication per day.  A patient can have dates populated for anywhere between 1 to 11 doses, and there are no middle doses that are missing information (e.g., if Dose5 is populated, by definition Dose1-Dose4 are populated).  I'm interested in getting the maximum number of consecutive days a patient took a dose of medication.
Here are 5 sample rows of data.

```
data have;
    input PATIENT_ID Dose1 :ddmmyy10. Dose2 :ddmmyy10. Dose3 :ddmmyy10. Dose4 :ddmmyy10. Dose5 :ddmmyy10. Dose6 :ddmmyy10. Dose7 :ddmmyy10. Dose8 :ddmmyy10. Dose9 :ddmmyy10. Dose10 :ddmmyy10. Dose11;
    format Dose1 Dose2 Dose3 Dose4 Dose5 Dose6 Dose7 Dose8 Dose9 Dose10 Dose11 ddmmyy10.;
    cards;
          1          01/01/2020 01/02/2020 01/03/2020 01/04/2020 01/05/2020 01/06/2020 01/07/20  1/08/2020 01/09/2020 01/10/2020 01/11/2020
          2          01/01/2020 01/02/2020 01/03/2020 01/05/2020 01/06/2020
          3          01/02/2020 01/04/2020 01/06/2020 01/08/2020 01/10/2020 01/12/2020 01/14/2020 01/16/2020 01/18/2020
          4          01/03/2020 01/04/2020 01/05/2020 01/06/2020 01/07/2020 01/08/2020 01/09/2020  1/10/2020 01/12/2020 01/13/2020
          5          01/01/2020 01/07/2020 01/08/2020 01/10/2020
;
run;
```

I would like to get the variable MAX_CONSECUTIVE_DAYS:

```
data want;
    input PATIENT_ID MAX_CONSECUTIVE_DAYS Dose1 :ddmmyy10. Dose2 :ddmmyy10. Dose3 :ddmmyy10. Dose4 :ddmmyy10. Dose5 :ddmmyy10. Dose6 :ddmmyy10. Dose7 :ddmmyy10. Dose8 :ddmmyy10. Dose9 :ddmmyy10. Dose10 :ddmmyy10. Dose11;
    format Dose1 Dose2 Dose3 Dose4 Dose5 Dose6 Dose7 Dose8 Dose9 Dose10 Dose11 ddmmyy10.;
    cards;
          1          11                  01/01/2020 01/02/2020 01/03/2020 01/04/2020 01/05/2020 01/06/2020 01/07/20  1/08/2020 01/09/2020 01/10/2020 01/11/2020
          2          3                   01/01/2020 01/02/2020 01/03/2020 01/05/2020 01/06/2020              
          3          1                   01/02/2020 01/04/2020 01/06/2020 01/08/2020 01/10/2020 01/12/2020 01/14/2020 01/16/2020 01/18/2020
          4          8                   01/03/2020 01/04/2020 01/05/2020 01/06/2020 01/07/2020 01/08/2020 01/09/2020  1/10/2020 01/12/2020 01/13/2020
          5          2                   01/01/2020 01/07/2020 01/08/2020 01/10/2020
run;
```

So far, I've only been able to figure out how to do it by brute force piecemeal.

```
data bruteforce;
    set have;
    if Dose2 =. then MAX_CONSECUTIVE_DAYS=1;
      else if Dose3=. then
      do;
        if Dose2-Dose1=1 then MAX_CONSECUTIVE_DAYS=2;
          else MAX_CONSECUTIVE_DAYS=1;
      end;
      else if Dose4=. then
      do;
        if Dose3-Dose1=2 then MAX_CONSECUTIVE_DAYS=3;
          else if (Dose2-Dose1=1) or (Dose3-Dose2=1) then MAX_CONSECUTIVE_DAYS=2;
          else MAX_CONSECUTIVE_DAYS=1;
      end;
      else if Dose5=. then
      do;
        if Dose4-Dose1=3 then MAX_CONSECUTIVE_DAYS=4;
          else if (Dose3-Dose1=2) or (Dose4-Dose2=2) then MAX_CONSECUTIVE_DAYS=3;
          else if (Dose2-Dose1=1) or (Dose3-Dose2=1) or (Dose4-Dose3=1) then MAX_CONSECUTIVE_DAYS=2;
          else MAX_CONSECUTIVE_DAYS=1;
      end;
     /*And so on and so forth until accounting for rows where Dose10 is populated*/
 run;
```

However, in my actual work, there are over 200 doses of medication, so doing a series of do loops with if-then-else statements doesn't make sense.  If I had to guess, the solution might have something to do with arrays, but I'm not sure where or how to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, thank you for providing a clear explanation of your problem and what you have tried so far :-)

Just a note. I changed your input data to have dates with mmddyy10 informat/format. I think what you want is to count consecutive days and not months.

Anyway, try this. Feel free to ask

```
data have;
infile datalines missover;
input PATIENT_ID (Dose1 - Dose11)(:mmddyy10.);
format Dose: mmddyy10.;
cards;
1 01/01/2020 01/02/2020 01/03/2020 01/04/2020 01/05/2020 01/06/2020 01/07/2020 1/08/2020 01/09/2020 01/10/2020 01/11/2020
2 01/01/2020 01/02/2020 01/03/2020 01/05/2020 01/06/2020
3 01/02/2020 01/04/2020 01/06/2020 01/08/2020 01/10/2020 01/12/2020 01/14/2020 01/16/2020 01/18/2020
4 01/03/2020 01/04/2020 01/05/2020 01/06/2020 01/07/2020 01/08/2020 01/09/2020 1/10/2020 01/12/2020 01/13/2020
5 01/01/2020 01/07/2020 01/08/2020 01/10/2020
;

data want(drop=c i);
   set have;
   array dose {*} Dose:;
   c = 1;
   do i = 2 to dim(dose);
      if dose[i] - dose[i-1] = 1 then c + 1;
      else do;
         if c > mc then mc = c;
         c = 1;
      end;
   end;
   if mc = . then mc = c;
run;
```

Result:

```
PATIENT_ID Dose1...Dose11 mc 
1 ... 11 
2 ... 3 
3 ... 1 
4 ... 8 
5 ... 2
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! Can you please explain how the array works with these lines of code (apologies for poor formatting, I can't figure out how to get line breaks in a comment): `else do;
         if c > mc then mc = c;
         c = 1;
      end;` What's the logic SAS is using to iterate to get values where MC>1?

Comment: The logic is this: 1) test if there is exactly 1 day between the two dates. 2) if there is, add 1 to c. if not, we have a 'break'. Therefore we set c back to 1. Also, test if c is greater than the current 'longest streak' (mc).

Answer (score 2):

Correct, a variable based `array` will let you iterate over the dates and compute the longest run.

Tip: Use a variable name as indicative of value content as possible.  `dose<n>` is less *meta* informative then `dose_date<n>`

A robust computation will check or account for edge cases such as no dosages.

Sample code:

There is a small (perhaps negligible) CPU cost to extracting a value from an array.  Suppose the array was named `x`. The computation `x[index]-x[index-1]` inside a loop repeats such a cost.
For example: `x[5]−[x4]` and `x[6]−x[5]`.  Storing an extracted value in a variable will reduce the repeated cost.

Data set option `keep=` is an explicit list of variables to be output.  Alternatively, `drop=_:` could be used to exclude worker variables (in this sample) whose names start with `_`.

```
data have;
infile datalines missover; input 
ID X1-X11; format _numeric_ 4.; datalines;
1 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11
2 01 02 03 05 06
3 02 04 06 08 10 12 14 16 18
4 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 12 13
5 01 07 08 10
6 01
7
8 01 03 05 07 09 11 13 15 17 19 21
;

data want(keep=id x: rl_max);
  set have;
  array X X:;

  if not missing(x1) then _rl = 1;  /* preset if not an edge case */
  _p = x1;

  rl_max = _rl;

  do _index = 2 to dim(X);
    _q = X[_index]; /* store extracted value in worker variable */
    if missing(_q) then leave; /* iterate as little as needed */
     
    if _q - _p = 1 then /* consecutive */
      _rl = sum (_rl, 1);
    else do; /* gap, check and reset */
      if _rl > rl_max then rl_max = _rl;
      _rl = 1;
    end;

    _p = _q;  /* current to previous */
  end;

  if _rl > rl_max then rl_max = _rl;   /* no gaps */
run;
```